# Pythonic Decoupling of Input and Resulting Object

Tags: python, oop, decoupling

I have various input streams that give information I want packaged into an object that I can then pass around to separate functions:

```
class FruitBasket:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

However, each data stream names the data I am looking for differently.  StreamA's input looks like this:

```py
{"apple" : 3, "banana" : 2, "citrus" : 0}
```

and StreamB's input looks like this:

```py
{"fruit1" : 1, "fruit2" : 7, "fruit3" : 4, "dog" : 21}
```

Currently my solution to this is to have a separate class that maps the information between the input data and the object output:

```py
class StreamAMap(Enum):
    a = "apple"
    b = "banana"
    c = "citrus"

class StreamBMap(Enum):
    a = "fruit2"
    b = "fruit1"
    c = "fruit3"
```

I then pass both this "map" class, the target object, and input data into a function:

```py
def translate(map_enum, target, data):
    translation = {}

    for item in map_enum:
        translation[item.name] = data[item.value]

    return(target(**translation))

data_a = {"apple" : 3, "banana" : 2, "citrus" : 0}
data_b = {"fruit1" : 1, "fruit2" : 7, "fruit3" : 4, "dog" : 21}

basket_1 = translate(StreamAMap, FruitBasket, data_a)
basket_2 = translate(StreamBMap, FruitBasket, data_b)
```

It works, but I am wondering if there is a more Pythonic way of achieving this.

**edit:**
The goal here is to keep `FruitBasket` completely decoupled from whatever stream may produce data that end up in it, i.e. every stream knows what information needs to go into `FruitBasket`, but regardless of what streams are added or removed in the future, I don't have to actually change anything about the `FruitBasket` class, but rather only ensure that each stream is returning a valid `FruitBasket` to the main application.  My current implementation requires only a "map" class be defined for each new stream I add, and I'm wondering if there is a "Pythonic" (built-in) way of doing this rather than rolling my own translate function to do it.

To clarify what I mean by "Pythonic", the "Pythonic" way of determining the mean of a list is `sum(list) / len(list)` rather than iterating through the list to increment a counter variable and add each item to a sum variable.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary? You never seem to refer to the enum values directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could certainly pass a dictionary into the function instead of an enumeration and do `for k, v in map_dict.items():` .  I was wondering more about the pattern than the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out a way to do this very simply and concisely:

```py
class FruitBasket:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class FruitBasketIntermediateA:
    def __init__(self, apple, banana, citrus, **kwargs):
        self.a = apple
        self.b = banana
        self.c = citrus

class FruitBasketIntermediateB:
    def __init__(self, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, **kwargs):
        self.a = fruit2
        self.b = fruit1
        self.c = fruit3

data_a = {"apple" : 3, "banana" : 2, "citrus" : 0}
data_b = {"fruit1" : 1, "fruit2" : 7, "fruit3" : 4, "dog" : 21}

my_fb_a = FruitBasket(**vars(FruitBasketIntermediateA(**data)))
my_fb_b = FruitBasket(**vars(FruitBasketIntermediateB(**data)))
```

If I was consuming hundreds of thousands of messages per second I would likely have to use something more performant, like the method in the original question but with dicts instead of enums, or using jsbueno's method, however the hard limit is orders of magnitude less so this works well for my needs and keeps things decoupled and concise.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about "Pythonic" forget about "OOP correct way" and think about keeping your sanity. The obvious way to keep your sanity there will be the one "OOP correct" and "Pythonic".

So, you have some information that is heterogeneous on the outside of your system, but you want a well defined single behavior for objects conveing this information inside your system.

The obvious solution is to have a class, in your system that will behave the same, with well defined attributes and methods, and have a way to *create* objects of that class that can cope with heterogeneous data input. And the same for output - if you have the requirement to output the information in more than one form, you write methods to transform your (uniform, in app) information into the specific form required for each output channel.

Talking in more concrete terms - your class should have the fields you need at hand for your app core business as attributes,  and either have a poymorphic initializer method, various helper methods to create instances from each input type, or a factory function (or set of factory functions) to create your instances.

But once they are created, they all should just have the `a`, `b` and `c` attributes.

The second pattern from the options I gave above could be a nice start:

```py
class FruitBasket:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    @classmethod
    def from_named_stream(self, stream):
        return FruitBasket(a=stream["apple"], b=stream["banana", c=stream["citrus"]) 

    # go on and create one such classmethod for each form of input data
```

Comment: Well put.  Remember the [Walt Whitman quotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) on the first page of the PEP-8 guidelines.  What works best for you in the long run *is* Pythonic.

Comment: I like this answer, but what I'm really looking for is `FruitBasket` to be completely ignorant of what stream is producing the data and to handle the repacking in the code for the stream, so that I can add or remove streams from the program at will without having to add code to `FruitBasket` or have a bunch of unused generator functions for streams I'll never use again.

Comment: Don't. It won't help you if "fruit basket " is ignorant and yo have to worry abut that in __all_your_code__. WHat you can do is to have functions that will create `FruitBascket` to be stand-alone functions or in other places, instead of being class methods. If you want to have to force each part of your system to rebuild the data in different sources, then your question have no meaning: you already opted for the worst thing you could do.